# After button click timer should start again

Tags: javascript, dom-events

```
<script>
    var minutes = 1;
    var seconds = 45;


    $(document).ready(function () {
        setInterval(startTimer, 1000);
    });
    
    function startTimer() {
        

        document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML = (minutes - 1) + ":" + --seconds;
        if (seconds == 0) {
            minutes--;
            if (minutes != 0) {
                seconds = 60;
            } else {
                seconds = 0;
            }

        }
        if (minutes == 0 && seconds == 0) {
            document.getElementById('next').click();
            minutes = 1;
            seconds = 45;

        }
        
   
    }
</script>
```

This is my code for the timer and it should restart after button click whose id is `#next`. I did many things but it won't work. Please help.

Button Id = Next

Comment: If you want to clear an interval, create a global scope variable to hook to your interval.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's my solution to your issue.

> I've noticed `$(document).ready()` so I instantly presumed you are
>   using `jQuery`.

`var timerInterval` is a direct reference to the timer that you started.

To stop the timer, use `clearInterval(timerInterval)` [Same story goes for `setTimeout()`].

I've changed your countdown timer because I couldn't be bothered fixing it.

---

```js
var timerInterval;

let minutes = 2;
let seconds = 42;

let duration = (minutes * 60) + seconds;
let display = document.querySelector('#timer');

function startTimer(duration, display) {
  var timer = duration, minutes, seconds;
  timerInterval = setInterval(function() {
    minutes = parseInt(timer / 60, 10)
    seconds = parseInt(timer % 60, 10);

    minutes = minutes < 10 ? "0" + minutes : minutes;
    seconds = seconds < 10 ? "0" + seconds : seconds;

    display.textContent = minutes + ":" + seconds;

    if (--timer < 0) {
      timer = duration;
      clearInterval(timerInterval);
    }
  }, 1000);
}

startTimer(duration, display);

$('button').click((e) => {
 clearInterval(timerInterval);
  startTimer(duration, display);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span id="timer"></span>
<br>
<button>Reset Timer</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Without the html I can't give you step by step but basically, you need to clear the interval before you can restart it.

```
<script>
    var minutes = 1;
    var seconds = 45;
    var interval_id=setInterval(startTimer, 1000);
    $('#next').on("click",function(){
        clearInterval(interval_id);
        minutes = 1;
        seconds = 45;
        document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML ="";
        interval_id=setInterval(startTimer, 1000);
    });
 function startTimer() {


    document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML = (minutes - 1) + ":" + --seconds;
    if (seconds == 0) {
        minutes--;
        if (minutes != 0) {
            seconds = 60;
        } else {
            seconds = 0;
        }

    }
    if (minutes == 0 && seconds == 0) {
        minutes = 1;
        seconds = 45;
    }


}
</script>
```

Comment: not worked. `$("#next").click(function(){
            console.log("clic");
            clearInterval(interval_id);
        });`

Comment: If you just want to reset the starting numbers when they click next, try setting resetting the minutes and seconds variables to their defaults

Answer (score 0):

You should not rely on setInterval (or setTimeout) to calculate a time value. It is not guaranted to be called at the specified interval. I believe in some case it could also be paused by the browser.

You could try something like this :

```
<span id='timer'></span>

<button id='next'>Next</button>

<script>

var btn = document.getElementById('next');

btn.addEventListener('click', function(e) { 
    // 10 is the duration in seconds
    startNextTimer(10, function() { alert('done!');} ); 
});

function startNextTimer(numSecondsDuration, callback) {
  var label = document.getElementById('timer');

  var endDate = new Date();
  endDate.setSeconds(endDate.getSeconds() + numSecondsDuration);

  var calcTimeLeft = function() { return Math.ceil((endDate - (new Date())) / 1000); };
  label.innerHTML = calcTimeLeft() + " secs";
  var intervalId = setInterval(function() {
     var numSecondsLeft = calcTimeLeft();
     if (numSecondsLeft <= 0) {
        clearInterval(intervalId);
        if (callback) {
            callback();
        }
     }
     label.innerHTML = numSecondsLeft + " secs";
  }, 500);

}

</script>
```